# Pass a variable from mongoose middleware to callback of model remove function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using middleware to do some pre-processing before removing a record from the database. However it would be very useful if I could pass on some information about the results of this pre-processing from the middleware to the model remove callback. Is this possible somehow?

```js
Movie.pre('remove', function(next) {
  var result = true;
  next();
});


movie.remove(function(err, result) {
  if (result === true) {
     // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inject `result` into the `remove` callback parameters, but this will work:

```
Movie.pre('remove', function(next) {
  this.result = true;  // Add a result property to the movie object being removed
  next();
});


movie.remove(function(err) {
  if (movie.result === true) {  // result property is available from the middleware
     // do something
  }
});
```